# Neo4j - Adding indexes correctly

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher

I have a kinda complex query for retrieving nodes of type `Post`. Query looks like this.

```
MATCH (t:Tag) WHERE t.name='CAT' with t
MATCH (t)-[:HAS_TAG]-(p:Post) WHERE p.approval <> 2 AND (p.blocked= false OR p.blocked IS NULL)
with p where p.property1 >= 10 AND p.property1 < 3000000000
with p where not exists(p.property2) or  (p.property2 >= 100 and p.property2 < 43000)
with p where not exists(p.property3) or  (p.property3 >= 100 and p.property3 < 43000)
with p where not exists(p.property4) or  (p.property4 >= 100 and p.property4 < 43000)
with p ORDER BY p.property5 DESC SKIP 0 LIMIT 10
RETURN p;
```

I have already added an index for the `name` property of `Tag` type. So when i run the profile query, it indicates that it uses that index on `name` property.

Now I want to use indexes to optimize other parts of this query as well. I am not sure how to do that since i have used `with` keyword to separate the filtering parts.

Should I create a composite index like this:`(property1, property2, property3, property4,approval,blocked)`

Or

should i create separate indexes for each property since they are separated by `with` phrases?.

Answer (score 0):

As you're not ANDing different properties, you would need to create an index for each property you're doing filtering against.

This [blog post](https://maxdemarzi.com/2020/02/19/composite-indexes-in-neo4j-4-0/) might be useful.